# quit the application and relaunch it again timer should resume time according to the allotted time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, nstimer, countdowntimer

I have countdown Timer. If I quit the application and relaunch it again timer should resume time according to the allotted time. Is it possible?

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 
                 target:self 
                 selector:@selector(timerFired) 
                 userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

- (void)timerFired
{
    if((currMinute>0 || currSeconds>=0) && currMinute>=0)
    {
        if(currSeconds==0)
        {
            currMinute-=1;
            currSeconds=59;
        }
        else if(currSeconds>0)
        {
            currSeconds-=1;
        }
        if(currMinute>-1)


        timeRemain=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@%02d",currMinute,@":",currSeconds];

    }
    else
    {
       [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Save the time remaining to `UserDefaults` when you exit the app then then read that value when the app starts back up. You can then continue with the time you have left. If you want it to act as if its continued counting then you probably want to save the time you exit the app to `UserDefaults` and then do some calculations based on the current time.

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
-(void)timerFired
{
    NSInteger currMin = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"currentMinute"];
    NSInteger currSec = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"currentSeconds"];

    if((currMin>0 || currSec>=0) && currMin>=0)
    {
        if(currSec==0)
        {
            currMin-=1;
            currSec=59;
        }
        else if(currSec>0)
        {
            currSec-=1;
        }
        if(currMin>-1)


            timeRemain=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d%@%02d",currMin,@":",currSec];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:currMin forKey:@"currentMinute"];
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:currSec forKey:@"currentSeconds"];


    }
    else
    {
        [timer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: Yah Thats ok.but relaunch it again timer should resume time according to the allotted time ? how to check with relaunch time?

Comment: Then you have to save date and time at Quit (applicationWillTerminate) and again check with launch(didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) then you can find diff between it that way you can calculate your resume time.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you need to store Future date which is as mention below.

Add Current Time while your are starting Timer and add Your minute & seconds what time you needed in it.

**For Example :**

```
currMinute = 2;
currSeconds = 30;

NSDate *dateFuture = [[NSDate date] dateByAddingTimeInterval:(currMinute*60)+currSeconds];
```

**Now store this future date into NSUserDefaults like this**

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"EndDate"]) {
   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dateFuture forKey:@"EndDate"];
}
```

**Start Your timer :**

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(timerFired)
                                           userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

> Note : Before start timer check if End Date is exist in UserDefaults
>   and End Date is grater than current date.

```
- (void)timerFired
{

    NSComparisonResult result = [[NSDate date] compare:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"EndDate"]];
    if ( result == NSOrderedDescending) {
        [timer invalidate];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"EndDate"];
    }else{
        NSTimeInterval secondsBetween = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"EndDate"]];

        NSLog(@"There are %f secondsBetween in between the two dates.", secondsBetween);
    }
}
```

Now you can get Your Remaining time after restart your app N number of time you will get updated time only.